# Wordpress pretty urls show blank page ( not found )

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried to check every blog post I found, but somehow I cannot manage to find the cause for this.

.htaccess file (as provided by wordpress):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I ensured that mod_rewrite module is available.

I also ensured to resave the page I've tested and the settings.

Memory Limit is 64M and php Version is 5.6

I'm out of ideas...

Example http://test.steinbeis-sibe.de/bewerber/

Comment: Do you wanna try this in [wordpress.se]?

Comment: Please give url if you have

Comment: @FrankProvost I have on solution

Comment: I've added an url

Comment: Comment out the start and end `IfModule` tags with `#`. If you get a 500 error, you don't have rewriting configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**common blank post reason**

- disable  plugin

  You have to disable all plugin and try to active one by one.If you have plugin related issue this will detect here.
- switch to default theme

  You have to try to active default theme.If you have theme related issue this will detect here.
- htaccess or link issue

  rename .htaccess and update param-link to default (page/post id).

Comment: @FrankProvost please switch to default theme and disable plugins also.an remove htaccess

Comment: Did you extract installation package to the root directory? Or is is located in WordPress directory inside your root directory?

Comment: apache configuration option         AllowOverride All

Comment: Get into your website's FTP space, and look for the .htaccess file
Highlight the .htaccess file in your FTP program, and open its CHMOD settings. It's probably set to 644. Change it to 666.
Go back into your Wordpress site's admin section, and navigate to Settings » Permalinks.

Comment: i switched theme - and tried ( i already switched back ) - .htaccess is 666 also tried 777 - i also verified its updated when making changes to the permalinks.
I don't have access to the apache config - is there a way to check if AllowOverride All is set?

Comment: Okay one more thing we can try here.

Comment: first edit post and update somthing and preview it.Is it visible??

Comment: It's not visible. Even though the permalinks is correct. Is there a way to programatically check if AllowOverride is set to all? without access to the config?

Comment: No issue with apache